# ContentControl.insertHTML gets progressively slower

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am trying to load all the ContentControls in the document. After that they need to be edited via a user-action. Inserting HTML works fine for the first few insertions but after the 3rd or so it keeps getting slower. It can take up to 5 minutes to insert the text, which is not suitable for a Taskpane Add In which should update live when the user types into a textbox.

I recreated the issue in ScriptLab. The Code loads all ContentControls like the real Add In and then shows a button InsertHTML which will insert 'a's into every ContentControl tagged with 'test'. It uses the `insertHTML(<html>, 'Replace)`-Method to do so. With every click on the button it gets worse.

https://gist.github.com/tillkaemmerer/6064d759dd1dbfd310378f9097d8fcdb

This problem occurs only in Word Online (Build 16.0.13924.41001). Word Desktop (Build 13801.20360) works  fine.

Comment: Problems in your gist: I press **Load** but nothing happens in the document; but "ContentControls loaded!" appears in the console. Pressing the **InsertHTML** button gives the error: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". Does the document need test content?

Comment: Yes, it requires a ContentControl which is tagged with "test".

Comment: Because your problem is with Word Online and there is no way to manually add a content control in Word Online, please update the gist so that the the content controls can be added through the add-in. Thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce this, although I don't see the slow down until about the 10th time I press the button. Please open a bug on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=). But please update the gist as I suggested, to make it easier for the engineers to reproduce.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I Updated the gist to create a ContentControl when pressing the 'Load' Button.